How can we know user location or Ip address in React?
I want to know user location and i tried multiple api but all of them are giving me wrong state and city name, if i don't provide ip address, like this api -> https://ipapi.co/json
but if i pass ip address to above api then i get correct state and city name.
So can anyone suggest how to get user ip address so i can pass in above url or how can i get user address like correct state and city. [I am running a react project]
Thank you

In a React application, you typically don't directly access a user's IP address from the client-side code due to security and privacy concerns. However, you can obtain the user's location using browser APIs or third-party services.
Getting User's Location:
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
      console.log(`Latitude: ${latitude}, Longitude: ${longitude}`);
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error('Error getting geolocation:', error);
    }
  );
} else {
  console.error('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
}

Third-Party IP Geolocation Services:
fetch('https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('User location:', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error fetching user location:', error);
  });

